# Joining two MySQL tables and then performing basic filtering on one of them

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, they look roughly like below:

Categories:

```
+----+-----------+--------+----------------+
| id | entity_id | set_id |      type      |
+----+-----------+--------+----------------+
|  1 |        49 |      1 | signup         |
|  2 |        57 |      1 | signup         |
|  3 |        65 |      1 | signup         |
|  4 |        69 |      1 | recommendation |
|  5 |        73 |      1 | signup         |
|  6 |        77 |      1 | recommendation |
|  7 |        23 |      2 | comment        |
|  8 |        45 |      2 | recommendation |
|  9 |        56 |      2 | signup         |
|  10|        76 |      2 | signup         |
+----+-----------+--------+----------------+
```

Steps:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| id | set_id | start_id | end_id |
+----+--------+----------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |       49 |     57 |
|  2 |      1 |       57 |     65 |
|  3 |      1 |       65 |     69 |
|  4 |      1 |       69 |     73 |
|  5 |      1 |       77 |     57 |
|  6 |      2 |       23 |     45 |
|  7 |      2 |       45 |     56 |
|  8 |      2 |       56 |     76 |
+----+--------+----------+--------+
```

I need to select the rows of a given `set_id` from `categories`, but only if their `entity_id` is found in `steps` in the `start_id` column but NOT the `end_id` column.

So from this example, these are the two records I would expect to be returned:

```
+----+-----------+--------+----------------+
| id | entity_id | set_id |      type      |
+----+-----------+--------+----------------+
|  1 |        49 |      1 | signup         |
|  6 |        77 |      1 | recommendation |
+----+--------+----------+-----------------+
```

I know how to perform a basic join on `set_id`, but I'm not sure how to search all the records of that `set_id` from `steps` and exclude those that have an `entity_id` that appears in `end_id`

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM categories JOIN steps ON categories.set_id = steps.set_id WHERE ....categories.entity_id is present in steps.start_id but not in steps.end_id??
```

How should this logic be properly formed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exists logic works well here and is also straightforward:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM categories c
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM steps s WHERE s.set_id = c.set_id AND c.entity_id = s.start_id)
    AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM steps s WHERE s.set_id = c.set_id AND c.entity_id = s.end_id);
```

The above query, read in plain English, says to find all category records such that there exists a matching record in `steps` where the `entity_id` matches the `start_id`, but there does *not* also exist a record in `steps` where the `entity_id` appears in `end_id`.

Comment: This is great, but how would I be able to feed it a variable `set_id`? (I realize I left that part out of my pseudocode) .

Comment: Looks like you can just add another statement after the where...
set_id = xzy
AND
EXISTS... etc

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause?  E.g. `WHERE set_id = 1` or maybe `WHERE set_id = ?` for a prepared statement?